# How to get a data-lnk-href inside a div? Beautiful Soap and Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to take all the underlined `data-lnk-href` in the web:

[image]

```html
<div id="28365533333.100500" class="ad-preview    ad-preview--has-desc" data-lnk-href="/alquilar/piso-ensanche_sar-28365533333_100500/">


<div id="28397541675.990666" class="ad-preview    ad-preview--has-desc" data-lnk-href="/alquilar/casa-urbanizacion_costa_mino_golf-28397541675_990666/">
    <div class="ad-preview__top">
```

It is from this page: https://www.pisos.com/alquiler/pisos-a_coruna/

I have tried this:

```
flats = soup.find_all('div', class_="ad-preview    ad-preview--has-desc")
for i in flats:
    print(i.find('a').attrs['data-link-href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

First select all flats

```
flats = soup.find_all("div", {"class" : "ad-preview ad-preview--has-desc"}
```

Then select the href element from each flat

```
flatlinks = [flat["data-lnk-href"] for flat in flats]
#['/alquilar/casa_pareada-ames_san_tome-29223728328_106900/', '/alquilar/piso-sada_centro_urbano-28401214803_101800/', '/alquilar/apartamento-concheiros_fontinas15703-29211123764_101800/', '/alquilar/piso-ensanche_sar15701-28400185769_101800/', '/alquilar/piso-ensanche_sar-28365533333_100500/', '/alquilar/casa-urbanizacion_costa_mino_golf-28397541675_990666/', '/alquilar/piso-ensanche15004-25921567538_100500/', '/alquilar/piso-cidade_vella_atochas_pescaderia15001-1672697006_100500/', '/alquilar/casa_pareada-campus_norte_san_caetano15704-27590604144_100500/', '/alquilar/piso-loios-29184165540_990666/', '/alquilar/piso-porta_nova15404-16734525644_106000/', '/alquilar/piso-ferrol_esteiro15403-77580144133_106000/', '/alquilar/duplex-perillo15172-29222505627_108900/', '/alquilar/piso-porto_do_son_centro_urbano-29238844842_106000/', '/alquilar/atico-ribeira_santa_uxia-25888982455_108500/', '/alquilar/piso-catro_caminos_a_gaiteira15009-30050053236_100500/', '/alquilar/piso-ensanche15004-29224222647_100500/', '/alquilar/piso-naron_a_gandara-30017787801_524615/', '/alquilar/piso-os_castros_castrillon_monelos-25860503904_524936/', '/alquilar/apartamento-catro_caminos_a_gaiteira15006-13337577273_100500/', '/alquilar/piso-cidade_vella_atochas_pescaderia-26676409070_524206/', '/alquilar/piso-ensanche15004-28405594045_109300/', '/alquilar/piso-naron_a_gandara15570-23389515305_106900/', '/alquilar/piso-cidade_vella_atochas_pescaderia15003-27564579054_101800/', '/alquilar/atico-escarabote-28430411775_524515/', '/alquilar/piso-cidade_vella_atochas_pescaderia15003-26669645871_100500/', '/alquilar/piso-ensanche_sar15701-26696435275_101800/', '/alquilar/piso-cidade_vella_atochas_pescaderia15001-30028901665_100500/', '/alquilar/piso-caranza-29226084718_106900/']
```